# Tkinter Scroll through a canvas of frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to add a scroll bar to a canvas filled with multiple MsgFrame classes. MsgFrame inherits from the tk.Frame class. I've tried multiple youtube videos and articles but none have worked.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
scrollBar= Scrollbar(root)
scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')
canvas = Canvas(root, yscrollcommand=scrollBar.set)
frames = []
for row, msg in enumerate(MESSAGES):
    frame = MsgFrame(msg, canvas, row*3+1)
    frames.append(frame)

for frame in frames:
    frame.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW, padx=5, pady=5)

canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollBar.config(command=canvas.yview)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the result of the code? How is it different to what you were expecting? Also aren't you missing the binding to `"<Configure>"`? Also you should be using `.create_window(...)` not `.pack()`. For more info look at [this](https://blog.teclado.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames/amp/).

Comment: You can't scroll frames added to a canvas with `pack`. A canvas will only scroll items added with the `create_*` functions.

Comment: @BryanOakley I tried that and the window gets cut in half with the scroll bar in the middle of the root window.

Comment: @TheLizzard the article worked but the canvas was split in half. I figured the rest out. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @03Wolf. Can you post script?